# How to compare dates independent of current culture in .NET

Tags: c#-2.0

I hardcode a trial expiration date in my .net 2.5 app. how do I compare it with the user's system date such that the comparison is accurate regardless of the user's culture settings?

```
DateTime maxTrialDate = DateTime.Parse("11/17/2020", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

DateTime curDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

//the next line of code uses the DateDiff method to compare the two dates -dont recall its //exact syntax.
```

On my XP machine the above works if the control panel regional setting for datetime is `en-US`, but if I change it to `en-AU`, then the above code that sets `curDate` fires a `FormatException "Date is not in a correct string format"`

Comment: Is there **any** good reason to take `Now`, convert it into a string, and then parse back?

Answer (score 5):

If you avoid using strings to represent the dates, you will not encounter this problem:

```
DateTime maxTrialDate = new DateTime(2020, 11, 17);

if (DateTime.Now.Date > maxTrialDate)
{
     // expired
}
```

The `DateTime` is created by explicitly defining the day, month and year components, so the regional settings will not confuse matters.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Now I don't need the CultureInfo class at all.

Answer (score 0):

What about just using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` all over the place?

Comment: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is *invariant*. It's basically always `en-US`, so the behavior would be the same. You want `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: That works for setting the maxTrialDate, but when used for the current date, I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `FormatException` is expected since you explicitly ask the parser to use `en-US`.

Try calling [the one-argument overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) of `DateTime.Parse()`, or alternatively, if you really want to use the two-args overload (*cough*FxCop*cough*), something like:

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTime.Parse("11/17/2020", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, in most places outside the US, the standard date format is dd/mm/yyyy, rather than the US standard of mm/dd/yyyy.  It might be that when trying to parse the date, it believes the 17 is the month, which is an invalid month, thus causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the Parse method if you are hardcoding  expiration date just compare it to 
DateTime.now

Comment: DateTime.now must somehow be converted to the en-US format, which is what the hard-coded date is in, so how do I do that?